# How to install ns2 on Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, ns2

If I upgrade Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04, will NS2 still be supported?

I am currently using NS2 on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, NS2 [is available](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/ns2) in 14.04 repository. Run the following to install it:

```
sudo apt-get install ns2
```